# Serialize svm model in text format

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm

I have trained a svm model using libsvm and the model is a java object that has been serialized in binary format.
And now I wonder if I can serialize the model in text format so that i can "better understand it"? Is that possible to read the model from the java object?

Any help would be appreciated.
Horace

Comment: Can you post the code you already have ? maybe a example ? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the method **svm.svm_save_model(String model_file_name, svm_model model)** to save your model it will generate a text file relatively easy to understand and which can be loaded in other versions of libsvm for other programming languages.